# Is it possible to print a custom object by passing it to Serial.print()?

Tags: esp8266, stream

I googled about it, but can't find the answer. As I would guess I would have to inherit from the Print class and somehow pass to its print methods the part of my object I would like to be printed. But I am not sure how to go about it or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a class called `Printable`. If you inherit from that, and implement the `size_t printTo(Print& p)` function, your object can then be passed to the print functions:

```
class myClass : public Printable {
    private:
        int _val1;
        int _val2;

    public:
        myClass(int v1, v2) : _val1(v1), _val2(v2) {}
        size_t printTo(Print& p) const {
             size_t r = 0;

             r += p.print("One: ");
             r += p.print(_val1);
             r += p.print(" Two: ");
             r += p.print(_val2);
             return r;
       }
};
```

Then:

```
myClass ob(4, 5);

Serial.println(ob);
=> One: 4 Two: 5
```

Comment: Majenko, thankyou very much for your answer. I got it working. Just little comment on your code. I think instead of "size_t printTo(Print& p)" should be "size_t printTo(Print& p) const". Thankyou

Comment: I just copied and pasted the prototype from the header.

Comment: I was getting an error of not overriding virtual function. Once added the const, all ok.

Comment: Ok. I have modified it for future reference

Comment: How are we supposed to know these things? The arduino documentation is quite... lacking... to say the best. Digging through the source code on github?