# Serial port usage in code

Tags: serial, c++

I want to write a function that defines a serial port based on a flag but I'm not sure it's possible.

For example:

```
void writeToSerial(bool useSerial1)
{
   SerialPortClass serialPortObject; // Is there some way of defining a generic Serial port object and reusing it below?

   if (useSerial1)
   {
      serialPortObject = Serial1;
   }
   else
   {
      serialPortObject = Serial2;
   }

   serialPortObject.write("test123");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing HardwareSerial and SoftwareSerial as a Class Property](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55742/passing-hardwareserial-and-softwareserial-as-a-class-property)

Answer (score 2):

According to sources at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial*` (on Windows platform), you can use pointer to `Stream` class (because `Serial`s are inherited from `Stream`).

So, your function could look like this:

```
void writeToSerial(bool useSerial1)
{
   Stream* serialPortObject;

   if (useSerial1)
   {
      serialPortObject = &Serial1;
   }
   else
   {
      serialPortObject = &Serial2;
   }

   serialPortObject->write("test123");
}
```

Comment: Note that the serial port has to be already initialized for this to work, as `Stream` lacks the `begin()` method. If you need to call either `begin()` or `end()`, you should use a pointer to `HardwareSerial`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper answer, but rather a suggestion to reconsider your
approach. The code posted in the question is obviously just a simplified
example, and printing “test123” is likely not your final goal. I assume
what you really want to do is print out some information about some
variables. You can then collect these variables into a data structure (a
C++ object) and make `writeToSerial()` a method of this object. The
object can the be printed like so:

```cpp
myDataStructure::writeToSerial(true);   // printed to Serial1
myDataStructure::writeToSerial(false);  // printed to Serial2
```

In this case, what I suggest is to instead explicitly `print()` (or
`println()`) the object to the relevant serial port, like this:

```cpp
Serial1.print(myDataStructure);
Serial2.print(myDataStructure);
```

This makes the code self-explanatory, and easier to maintain.

Obviously, you cannot just print arbitrary objects this way, as
`Serial1` and `Serial2` would have no idea about how to serialize them.
But the thing is, you can teach them! Make your class derive from
`Printable`, implement the virtual `printTo()` method, and you will be
able to print it to any serial port, LCD, or whatever understands
`print()`:

```cpp
class MyDataStructure : public Printable {
public:
    size_t printTo(Print& p) const {
        return p.print("test123");
    }
};

MyDataStructure someData;

void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600);
    Serial1.println(someData);
    Serial2.println(someData);
}

void loop(){}
```

See the answer to [Is it possible to print a custom object by passing it
to Serial.print()?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53732/is-it-possible-to-print-a-custom-object-by-passing-it-to-serial-print) for an example with actual data in the
object.